# access iframe links

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a website, that has google ads, to display its ads. I want to keep track of the url's that are being displayed every time a visitor visits the page.

I have tried using twill, BeautifulSoup, nodejs jsdom, but the page returned excludes the google ads links and returns just the page.

how can I do  this, for example, if I inspect the element with google chrome or firefox, I can view the links, but from the command line, I am not aware if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, for cross-domain security reasons. Sorry.